# Laravel 5.5 Cache files deleted after reload page

Tags: laravel, caching

First of all, I'm sorry with my English.

I'm doing a project using Laravel 5.5.* . When I load the user dashboard index, the function returns me a view with some information. When this view is totally loaded, I execute an AJAX call, which will bring me a chart.

So far so good, although it last too many seconds to finish. That's why I want to use cache (file type option).

The problem is that, when I reload the page, it seems like if Laravel deletes all cache files and try to repeat all the steps, instead of using all data saved in cache. I've tried to search information about this problem  without success.

Does anybody know how to resolve it?

PS: Probably my code will be improved later, but the thing here is about cache

This is a part of my code

```
if(!cache()->has('incomes') || !cache()->has('total') || !cache()->has('dates'))
        {
            $end_date = Carbon::now();
            $start_date = Carbon::now()->subDays(30);

            if(!cache()->has('dates'))
            {
                $formated_dates = $this->generateDateRange($start_date, $end_date,'d/m/Y');
                cache()->put('dates', $formated_dates, $this->getDiffInMinutes());

            }

            if(!cache()->has('incomes') || !cache()->has('total'))
            {
                $dates = $this->generateDateRange($start_date, $end_date,'Ymd');
                $response = json_decode($this->graphics->getDataIncomeGraphics($dates, 1,1,1)->getBody()->getContents());


                $success = ($response->success <= 0) ? 0 : 1 ;
                if(!$success)
                {
                    $strErr = 'ERROR';
                    $incomes = '';
                    return response()->json([
                        'success' => $success,
                        'error' => [$strErr],
                        'incomes' => $incomes,
                    ]);
                }

                $minutes = $this->getDiffInMinutes();
                cache()->put('incomes', $response->incomes, $minutes);
                cache()->put('total', $response->total, $minutes);
            }
        }

        return response()->json([
            'success' => $success,
            'error' => [$strErr],
            'incomes' => cache('incomes'),
            'dates' => cache('dates'),
            'total' => cache('total'),
        ]);
```

Thank you in advanced to everyone.

Comment: What's the code for `$this->getDiffInMinutes()` look like? Is it possible that's returning `null` (or interpreted as `0`)? That would cause your caches to expire immediately.

Comment: Ohh, sorry. I've forgotten to add these part of code. getDiffInMinutes() is to get the number of minutes between now and the beginning of the next day (00:00:00), because I want to change cache data once per day. I've test the function and returns data correctly

Comment: I do something similar in one of my projects; set a cache and update it every X minutes, but I use `Cache::forever()`, and a CRON script to update it (regardless of whether or not it exists). Would something like that work for you?

Comment: Thank you for your help, Tim. However, it doesn't work yet. I try to use Cache::remember and Cache::forever but It still deletes the cache files I previously stored in "storage/cache/data". It's weird because when I debug my code I see that the cache files are created, but when I refresh the page and stops in the breakpoint, these files are gone.

Comment: Is it possible that, prior to call by AJAX to this function, if I return the view Laravel clear the cache? I mean, firstly I load the dashboard index view to the user and show in it a spinner. After that, when $(document).ready, I call by AJAX to the function and do all the stuff commented previously. If it's so, what solution do I have to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: I've just tracked my code. The exact moment in which Laravel delete my cache files is when I return the view and it is building the response (before the AJAX call). I'm not sure the solution of this problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem and the solution. I had a mistake in one of my partials in which I tried to flush the cache once the user clicked the logout button.

Thank you very much Tim for your answers, and sorry to bother all of you with my mistake.